# Layouts - how to fill the gap between a top bar and a bottom bar

Tags: android-layout

I have a Toolbar at the top of my App and a BottomNavigationView (aka Tab controller) at the bottom.

I need to setup a Frame layout so that it fills the gap between them. This will hold the content for a selected tab.

This sounds simple, and I am a little surprised I have having problems here.

I have tried to use layout_above and layout_below but that fails to render the frame (background yellow so I can see it). Unless that is I add an explicit height which obviously I dont want to do.

Any ideas please :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="#007AFF"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
              app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/frame_fragmentholder"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@color/yellow"
          android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
          android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
          android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
          app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
          android:background="#007AFF"
          app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this seems to be to set the bottom edge of the Frame to the bottom edge of the bottom nav bar, but then also allow for the height of the nav bar by adding a margin_bottom attribute. This has the effect of making the bottom edge of the Frame == top edge of the bottom bar.

```
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottom_nav"
   android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"



  <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/frame_fragmentholder"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/yellow"
          android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
          layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottom_nav"
          android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```